# eww filter rules

Tags: html, eww

emacs-w3m has very useful function: w3m-filter. Namely, one can change html before rendering it.

Does eww have something similar?

For example on some site i want to change:

```
<span class="tag">tag</span>
```

to

```
 <span class="tag">[tag]</span>
```

How to do this in eww?